# How to change some part of example block body text size in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontsize

I would like to have a part of the title of a beamer `block` with a smaller font. Something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{exampleblock}{here default size of text but  \small here is small text}
    Test
  \end{exampleblock}
  \begin{alertblock}{Game theory \small page 78 springer}
    Test
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. If I get it right, you can `\usepackage{relsize}` and replace the `\small` by `\relsize{<factor>}`, and in `<factor>` you put a negative integer at your taste.

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik i tried your way but it doesn't work the problem that even i add \small or \relsize{} still the same size for the whole title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work properly because you don't know what is the current font size, and `\small` is an "absolute" font size.

Your code would work if you replaced `\small` by `\tiny`, for example. But if you don't want to bother finding out what is the current font size you are using you can `\usepackage{relsize}` to set a **rel**ative **size** to the current font, like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{here default size of text but{\relsize{-2} here is small text}}
    Test
  \end{block}
  \begin{alertblock}{Game theory{\smaller[2] page 78 springer}}
    Test
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will switch to a font 2 sizes smaller (see: [this page](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/)). So if your is, say, `\small`, with `\relsize{-2}` (which is the same as `\smaller[2]`), you get a font in `\scriptsize`.

The result is like this:

[image]

P.S.: I could not compile your `exampleblock` environment, so I changed to `block`.

Comment: op code works as is, so i do not understand what is the problem. for example `\begin{exampleblock}{here default size of text but  \footnotesize here is small text}
    Test
  \end{exampleblock}`, gives the same result as your solution.

Comment: @Zarko I really don't know why. Maybe I messed something up with my TeX distribution, because in another computer it worked fine. Even though, that's just an observation for the change I made. The font size change works all the same.